# BibTeX entry including "Foreword by"?

Tags: bibtex

What is the best practice for including "Foreword by" (or its equivalent) for @BOOK entries in BibTeX?  The problem with `NOTE =` is that it appears at the end of the typeset entry whereas I'd like it immediately after the author.

When I use this:

```
@BOOK{Hassrick:16,
       AUTHOR = "Peter H. Hassrick",
        TITLE = "Frederic Remington:  {A} catalogue raisonn{\'e} {II}",
        NOTE = "Foreward by {B}ruce {B}.~{E}ldredge",
        SERIES = "The {C}harles {M}.~{R}ussell {C}enter {S}eries on {A}rt and {P}hotography of the {A}merican {W}est",
        FOREWORD = "Bruce B. Eldredge",
    PUBLISHER = "University of Oklahoma Press", 
      ADDRESS = "Norman, OK",
         YEAR = "2016"
}
```

I get:

[image]

I would prefer the "Foreward by Bruce B. Eldredge" to appear immediately below the listing for the author.

Comment: Foreword or forward?

Comment: Please clarify what you're trying to achieve. E.g., are you trying to cite a passage in the foreword section or chapter of an entry of type `@book`? If so, is the foreword written by the same author(s) as the rest of the book is? Or are you just trying to mention that the book has a foreword written by <insert name here>? If it's the latter, what information are you trying to convey? E.g., is there a reason why the readers of your document should care about who wrote the foreword?

Comment: See [Foreword vs. Forward: What’s the Difference?](https://writingexplained.org/foreword-vs-forward-difference)

Comment: @Mico.  Exactly!  From your link:  "What does foreword mean? Foreword only has one meaning in modern usage: a short introductory section in a book. A foreword is typically written by a person other than the main author."  See, for instance, my book cover:  https://www.amazon.com/HALs-Legacy-2001s-Computer-Reality/dp/0262692112/ref=sr_1_1?keywords=hal%27s+legacy&qid=1571430454&sr=8-1 . And YES readers should care that the Foreward to my book was written by one of the most celebrated science fiction authors of all time, the creator of the source of my book (for instance).

Comment: So why do you insist on spelling the word as "foreward"?

Comment: From the amazon.com entry for the book at https://www.amazon.com/Frederic-Remington-Catalogue-Raisonné-Photography/dp/0806152087/ref=sr_1_1?keywords=Hassrick+frederic+remington&qid=1571430388&sr=8-1: "by Peter H. Hassrick (Editor), Bruce B. Eldredge (Foreword)". Aside: The surname of the author of the *foreword* to the book is spelled "Eldredge", not "Eldridge". Or does amazon.com maybe have this all wrong?

Comment: @Mico:  Glad we now both agree that "Foreword" (not "Forward") is correct.  Whew!

Comment: So if you agree with me that "foreword" is the correct spelling of the term in question, why do you insist on using "foreward" in all occurrences of the term in the body of your posting?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork -- Now that it's agreed that "Foreword" is the correct spelling, it would be a good idea to update the question header and text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could insert a foreword-related blurb into the entry's `title` field.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{filecontents}{stuffx.bib}
@BOOK{Hassrick:16,
  EDITOR    = "Peter H. Hassrick",
  TITLE     = "\textit{(Foreword by Bruce B. Eldredge.)} Frederic Remington: 
               A Catalogue Raisonn{\'e}~II",
  SERIES    = "The Charles M.~Russell Center Series on Art and Photography 
               of the American West, vol.~22",
  PUBLISHER = "University of Oklahoma Press", 
  ADDRESS   = "Norman~OK",
  YEAR      = "2016",
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{geometry} % set text block parameters suitably
\usepackage[authoryear,round]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}% or some suitable bibliography style

\begin{document}
\cite{Hassrick:16}
\bibliography{stuffx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, that will work.  Thanks.  (accept)  I do think, though, at some point *BibTeX* should support a `FOREWORD BY` entry.